# Numpy vectorize with signature

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone explain how does the signature works with numpy's vectorize?

I have read [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). It is confusing and has a very tiny part dedicated to signatures
I have googled numpy vectorize signature and all I could find was very particular examples without a general explanation.
I could not find any doc where the rules of use of signature is explained.

For example what does this mean?

```
ff=np.vectorize(a_function,signature="(),(),(),()->(2)")
```

where the function is

```
def a_function(a,b,c,d):
    # something here
```

I am guessing (because it is not explained anywhere) that the first four () correspond to the arguments of the function?? Alright... but what does the `(2)` mean? Is it a dimension?

Any link to some kind of tutorial or documentation **to signatures** specifically would help too (not to vectorize in general)

Comment: I think this might be useful to explain the signature syntax  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/generalized-ufuncs.html#generalized-universal-function-api

Comment: `vectorize` has a performance disclaimer.  And that's even truer when using the signature.  Don't put too much effort into understanding this.

Comment: It's not clear whether `np.vectorize` use of `signature` exactly matches the 'gerneralized ufunc' usage.  The basic pattern of using one `()` per input and output term holds, but whether the number or symbol inside matters is less clear.  Where did you see an example like '(),()->(2)'?  By default `vectorize` passes scalar arguments to your function, and expects a scalar (read about `otypes`).  `signature` lets you pass subarrays, with the symbols determining the number of dimensions, '(n,m)'.  I have answered a number of `np.vectorize` questions, but seldom has `signature` been essential.

Comment: When I've answered `signature` questions in the past, I generally have experimented, and found combos that work.  Trying something and paying attention to the error message can also be instructive.  The traceback also gives us an idea of how it works - or doesn't.  It also tells me that `vectorize` is defined in `numpy/lib/function_base.py`, so you can study the code for yourself.

Comment: 'very tiny part dedicated to signatures', that's a good indication that's it's a tiny part of the functionality as well.

Comment: @hpaulj That is a very good side issue. I read in some sources that is more efficient than loops. But in other sources, I read the opposite. Has  performance ever been measured seriously?

Comment: I used to say that `vectorize` (without signature) was slower than the equivalent list comprehension.  But in more recent SO tests,  I found that it scales better, so that at some (vague) size, it is faster.  Never the speed improvement of true numpy vectorized code (with compiled code).  Another variant is `np.frompyfunc`, which just returns object dtype results.  The

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the signature string "(),(),(),()->(2)" is used to specify the input and output signatures of the function a_function.

1. The four sets of () in "(),(),(),()" correspond to the input arguments of a_function, which expects four input arguments: a, b, c, and d. Each () indicates an argument's position and does not specify any further structure.
2. The -> in the signature string separates the input signature from the output signature.
3. (2) in ()->(2) specifies the output signature. In this case, (2) indicates that the output of the vectorized function will be a 1-dimensional NumPy array with a shape of (2,). This means that the function a_function should return a tuple or an array with two elements.

Comment: Can you give an example where it that `2` actually matters?

Answer (score 0):

The `()`'s to the left of the `->` correspond to `a_function`'s input `arg`uments while those to the right correspond to the outputs:

```
def a_function(a, b, c):
    return a*b*c

a_vectorized_function = np.vectorize(a_function, signature="(a),(b),(c)->(d)")
print(a_vectorized_function(np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]), np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]), np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]])))
```

These signature `args` can be specified, whether by variable names (e.g. `a`, `b`, `c`) or index:

```
def a_function(a, b, c):
    return a*b*c

a_vectorized_function = np.vectorize(a_function, signature="(0),(1),(2)->(3)")
print(a_vectorized_function(np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]), np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]), np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]])))
```

In fact, you could plug any number in as it doesn't correspond to the dimensions or shapes:

```
def a_function(a, b, c):
    return a*b*c

a_vectorized_function = np.vectorize(a_function, signature="(a),(b),(c)->(513)")
print(a_vectorized_function(np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]), np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]), np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]])))
```

still outputs:

```
[[0 1 8]
 [0 1 8]]
```

Changing the output dimensions/shapes takes place in `a_function`, and we'd have to use `a_function` that `return`s matching number of elements or a tuple, and no the `(2)` doesn't carry any specific meaning as the input/output parameters are only positional so we can even keep them blank):

```
def a_function(a, b, c):
    return a*b, b*c

a_vectorized_function = np.vectorize(a_function, signature="(),(),()->(),()")
print(a_vectorized_function(np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]), np.array([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]), np.array([[0, 1, 2]])))
```

Outputs:

```
(array([[0, 1, 4],
       [0, 1, 4]]), array([[0, 1, 4],
       [0, 1, 4]]))
```

Comment: Looks like the number of numbers or symbols in the () matter, but not their values.  They determine the number of dimensions to expect/pass through, but I don't think `vectorize` actually check the dimensions - of the inputs or outputs.

Comment: @hpaulj that's what I was trying to convey if it wasn't clear. `vectorize` doesn't check shapes/dimensions, just input and output represented as positional args with `()`.

Comment: so it is just an indication (perhaps to the coder) but not enforced in any way... interesting